# Split array into parts to paginate

Tags: python, list, slice

Let's say I have an array:

```
["Ford","BMW","Audi","Tesla","BMW","Bentley","Chevrolet","Lexus","Mazda","Maserati","Mini"]
```

then if i like to print 3 elements per page(In the terminal) i am expecting the following output

```
"Ford","BMW","Audi" (First page) 
"Tesla","BMW","Bentley" (Second Page)
"Chevrolet","Lexus","Mazda" (Third page)
```

I'm thinking of slicing but I have no idea exactly how to do it. The elements count per page depends on user input and for every 'x' elements the page count will be added by 1. I'm printing the output in the terminal.

Comment: What is a page when it comes to a terminal? Does the a predefined number of rows define a page? A terminal window can be resized to your wish, so how do we define a page?

Comment: @clmo Yes, the predefined number of rows define a page. If the number is 3, then print list[0] to list[2] into rows and then iterate for the next 3 elements in the list

Comment: @John can you clarify this " for every 'x' elements the page count will be added by 1"? after printing first page does it asl for any user input?

Comment: You can use this slicing: [cars[i::4] for i in range(4)]

Comment: you can use `for`-loop with `range(1, len(data), 3)` and `data[i:i+3]`. OR `while data:` with `page_data = data[:3]` and `data = data[3:]`

Comment: @deadshot i have 2 variables: page_size, page and the default values are 0 and 1 respectively. So I when the page_size is set to a number(let's say 3) then I would like to print out only the first 3 elements then increment the page variable by 1. I'm not sure pagination is possible in PyCharm's terminal if it's not then I would just like to print out the first 3 elements then count the total page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split data using `for`-loop and `range(len())`

```
data = ["Ford","BMW","Audi","Tesla","BMW","Bentley","Chevrolet","Lexus","Mazda","Maserati","Mini"]

page_size = 3

pages_data = []

for i in range(0, len(data), page_size): 
    pages_data.append(data[i:i+page_size])

print(pages_data)
```

Result:

```
[ ['Ford', 'BMW', 'Audi'], ['Tesla', 'BMW', 'Bentley'], ['Chevrolet', 'Lexus', 'Mazda'], ['Maserati', 'Mini'] ]
```

and now you can use it as `pages_data[page]`

---

You can do this also using `while` but it will destroy original list

```
data = ["Ford","BMW","Audi","Tesla","BMW","Bentley","Chevrolet","Lexus","Mazda","Maserati","Mini"]

page_size = 3

pages_data = []

while data:
    pages_data.append(data[:page_size])
    data = data[page_size:]

print(pages_data)
```

Result the same:

```
[ ['Ford', 'BMW', 'Audi'], ['Tesla', 'BMW', 'Bentley'], ['Chevrolet', 'Lexus', 'Mazda'], ['Maserati', 'Mini'] ]
```

---

In both you can do

```
print('total pages:', len(pages_data))

for number, data in enumerate(pages_data, 1):
    print(number, "|", ", ".join(item))
```

Result:

```
total pages: 4

1 | Ford, BMW, Audi 
2 | Tesla, BMW, Bentley
3 | Chevrolet, Lexus, Mazda 
4 | Maserati, Mini
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are on linux you should be able to use `stty -a` to see information about your terminal. Somewhere in there you should see how many rows you have. When you get this number you can print `rows - n` newlines after each of the `n` elements you print in your script. Just make sure you don't resize your terminal afterwards  . If you want, you could also use the [os library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) (or something similar) to query for the rows and automatically adjust the number of newlines to print in your script.

Comment: I'm not on linux, i'm running code on PyCharm. The pagination i meant is to print out the number of rows depending on user input then iterate the following elements in the list

Comment: @John but the example you posted has one row for each page

Comment: Could you edit your question to include your code and some more details? It is a little unclear what you are after